# ¿Como puedo modificar y eliminar una cadena de strings en C++?

Tags: c++, string, consola

El problema que tengo en c++ no sé como se modifica y elimina la cadena soy un poco nueva en esto y pues ya tengo gran parte del código y cuando se ejecuta todo va perfecto, cuando le doy la opción del menú a modificar no hace nada y cuando regreso al menu principal y le doy en la segunda opción solo me muestra la anterior que ya había escrito por ejemplo me muestra la palabra "Hola" necesito ayuda. Gracias abajo le estaré dejando un link para que vean el código fuente esta en drive.
[Aquí puedes ver mi código fuente](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ke1jIf-ZOBKEu004RwBa9cJk_mvfmqy/view?usp=sharing) 
[image: Esta es la parte de la modificación pero cuando voy a mostrar la palabra solo queda guardada con la anterior]

```
void modificar()
{
    cout<<"Ingrese la palabra que desea modificar: ";
    cout<<"Ingrese la palabra para poder modificarla: ";
    cin>>bpalabra;
    
    
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hola aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como podrias modificar la palabra,para modificar la palabra tienes que leerla nuevamente el archivo

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    using namespace std;
    void modificar()
    {
        string palabra;
   
    
        cout<<"ingrese la modificacion de la palabra";
        cin>>palabra;
        cout<<palabra;
        
    }
```